# When Ubuntu Server restarts  eth0  Doesn't come back up

Tags: 11.10, server, networking, ethernet

Every time I restart my Ubuntu Server 11.10 I can't ssh into it because ETH0 doesn't come up automatically. I never had this problem before upgrading to 11.10.
I have to login to the server and start the ETH0 manually. I would appreciate it any help. Thanks.

Here is my `/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
#The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface

iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.102
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    network 192.168.1.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Comment: Hi Joel, there was a change made in 11.10 to make sure that the system doesn't go into runlevel 2 before all interfaces have come up. Can you add to the question the output of ls -lR /run/network ? Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem, upgrade to 11.10 and eth0 does not start

Answer (score 9):

Joel, add a line with `auto eth0` before the `iface eth0 inet static` line, that should bring it up on boot.

Comment: SpamapS, the command didn't run..joel@Snoopy:/etc/network$ sudo ls -lR /run/network
ls: cannot access /run/network: No such file or directory.... then i deleted the /network and it ran but the output was too long to paste here.

Comment: If you run "sudo ifconfig eth0 up" when you log in on console, it brings up the interface?  Can you grep for eth0 in /var/log/syslog or dmesg and paste any interesting output that you get?

Comment: @deej +1, fixed me up.

Comment: I'd commented this out after configuring an Ubuntu 14.04 VM; uncommented this, and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had, and solved, a similar problem--perhaps my solution will work for you. The problem in my case was that in `/etc/network/interfaces` I had both eth0 and vin to auto as shown below:

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# The INside Virtual Network
auto vin
iface vin inet dhcp
bridge_ports eth0
bridge_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

After I commented out the first line, changing it to

```
#auto vin
```

the eth0 worked.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as it says, it could not find `/run/network`. That's why it doesn't start with `/etc/init.d/networking start`

I have the same problem, just a few days ago and still trace the failure since the directory gets destroyed every reboot.

If you simply create the `/run/network` directory you'll be able to start the network with a configured `ethX` but you'll lose it again next reboot. I haven't figured out what service is so persistent to destroy my work every time. Try it, creating a directory can't hurt too much.

Comment: It's not that anyone or anything is deleting your directory. `/run` is usually stored in RAM (filesystem type `tmpfs`) so it isn't persistent over reboots.

Answer (score 1):

Found a link with the answer.

It seems the move from `/var/run` to `/run` did not work during the upgrade process.

I fixed with this:

```
cd /var
mv run _run
ln -s /run .
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran across this webpage http://pingbin.com/2011/02/ubuntu-eth0-missing-after-reboot/
it seems to make a lot of sense, check it out.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

After restart `eth0` does not come up. My problem was `auto eth0` in `/etc/network/interfaces` was commented:

```
#auto eth0
```

Removed the `#` and it's OK.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your answer while possible may be a bit late as the OP already accepted the other answer. Your help is of course appreciated, however you might be better served by focusing your efforts on the [unanswered questions](//askubuntu.com/unanswered)